# Take the current time of the slider and play the song

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayer

Currently I'm working on a project in swift 3.0 where I have a UISlider that track the progressTime of a song and it updates the value accordingly. Therefore as the progressTime goes on it updates its value and the slider starts moving, so once the progressTime comes to an end so does the slider stops. While serving this purpose my requirement is to play the song from the point if the user drags the slider to a particular random position. So wherever the user drags the slider the song should play the song from that particular time. My partially done code as bellow, how would I change the logic in my function ??.

```
func trackTime() {
    let interval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 2)
    player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (progressTime) in

        let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)

        let secondsString = String(format:"%02d", Int(seconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)))
        let minutesString = String(format:"%02d", Int(seconds/60))



        //progress bar and end time
        if let duration = self.player?.currentItem?.asset.duration {

            let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
            let endTimeSeconds = String(format:"%02d", Int(durationSeconds/60))
            self.progressSlider.value = Float(seconds/durationSeconds) 
            self.progressSlider.isContinuous = false

            let newDuration = durationSeconds - seconds

            let endSecondsString = String(format:"%02d", Int(newDuration.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)))

            self.endtime = "\(endTimeSeconds):\(endSecondsString)"

        }
        self.endTimeLabel.text = self.endtime
        self.startTimeLabel.text = "\(minutesString):\(secondsString)"
    })
}
```

And once I press the play button it works as bellow

```
@IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if newRowSelected == true{
        if(isNewPathSelected){
            print("player")
            let url:URL = savePath!
            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL)
            player=AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
            let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
            playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 50) // actually this player layer is not visible
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            isNewPathSelected = false
        }

        if player?.rate == 0 // this means if its not playing
        {
            print("Playing")
            player!.play()
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause_button"), for: UIControlState.normal)

            trackTime()

        } else {
            player!.pause()
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play_button"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
    }else{
        showAlert()
    }

}
```

Comment: which issue faced here and what you want to do ?

Comment: if the user drags the slider, the song should play the song from that particular time

Comment: try this :     player.currentTime = NSTimeInterval(slder.value)

Comment: where should i do it

Comment: you need to add inside of slider target selector method :@IBAction func slide(_ slider: UISlider) {
    player.currentTime = TimeInterval(slider.value)
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add slider selector method as below :

```
  self.progressSlider.addTarget(self, action: Selector("touchUp:"), forControlEvents: [UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside])
```

**Selector method for slider**

```
func touchUp(sender:AnyObject?) {
         var showingTime: : CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(slider.value, 1);
         player.seek(toTime: showingTime, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)    
    }
```

Comment: where should i add the " self.progressSlider.addTarget(self, action: Selector("touchUp:"), forControlEvents: [UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside])" . method ??

Comment: in viewDidLoad.

Comment: did you used slider using storyboard or coding ?

Comment: i used storyboard to connect the outlet

Comment: then now take IBAction of that slider and in that function use above line.

Comment: it will be look like as @IBAction func slide(_ slider: UISlider) {
}

Comment: still it says  "binary operator "*" cannot be applied to operands of type float and int"

Comment: (sender.value * 1000, 1000)

Comment: this code will start the song from the beginning plus didnt play from the dragged point

Comment: this is correct but you need to calculate CMTime from slider value .

Comment: @danu try now .

Comment: still the same result. once i drag to a new position it'll go back to the time zero. is there anything i need to change in my button press (play button as in the code above)

Comment: can you print your showingTime in console and let me know.

Comment: or replace with **player.seek(to time: showingTime)**

Answer (score 0):

```
 @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
   // var showingTime: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(sender.value), 1);

    if let duration = player?.currentItem?.duration {
        let totalsecs = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
        let val = Float64(sender.value) * totalsecs

     let seekTime = CMTime(value: Int64(val), timescale: 1)
     player?.seek(to: seekTime, completionHandler: { (completedSeek) in

     })
    }


}
```